# Mixing UNION ALL and DISTINCT in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2014 database. I am building a stored procedure that will return counts across several tables that match certain criteria. At this time, I have the following:

```
SELECT 'Table1' TableName, COUNT(0) TotalRows FROM dbo.[SomeTable] 

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [Name]) AS 'Department' FROM [Department] 

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [SubDepartment]) AS 'SubDepartment' FROM [Department] 

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Table2' TableName, COUNT(0) TotalRows FROM dbo.[AnotherTable]
```

When I execute this SQL, I get an error that says:

> All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

If I remove the two lines that begin with `SELECT COUNT(...` it works just fine. However, I need to get the number of department names and the number of sub-department names. How can I do this while still getting the counts from the other tables?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you haven't just mixed up your columns and it should be `SELECT 'Department', COUNT(DISTINCT [Name])`?

Comment: @JeroenMostert sigh... you are correct.  Thank you for pointing out my folly. I was too close to the problem to see my own mistake.